# cannot compress stream of data setting a dictionary with zlib

Tags: c, dictionary, compression, zlib, deflate

I have been attempting to set a dictionary in zlib by modifying the zpipe.c example. Namely, I have a file with 32768 characters that I want to turn into a dictionary. So I modified zpipe (http://www.zlib.net/zpipe.c).

On the def() function, I added:

```
char dict[32768];
FILE *fd = fopen("dictB.txt", "r");
ssize_t test = fread(dict, 32768, 1, fd);
int lenDict = (int) sizeof(dict);
fclose(fd);
```

After deflateInit(), I have added the following

```
ret = deflateSetDictionary(&strm, (const Bytef*) dict, lenDict);
```

For good measure, I added the deflateSetDictionary and every point before calling deflate()

On the inf() function, I added the same dictionary (repeating for completeness):

```
char dict[32768];
FILE *fd = fopen("dictB.txt", "r");
ssize_t test = fread(dict, 32768, 1, fd);
int lenDict = (int) sizeof(dict);
fclose(fd);
```

and after the inflate() call, I modified zpipe.c such that it could accept a dictionary call:

```
ret = inflate(&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);
if (ret==Z_NEED_DICT){
   ret = inflateSetDictionary(&strm, (const Bytef*) dict, lenDict); 
}
assert(ret != Z_STREAM_ERROR);  /* state not clobbered */
switch (ret) {
 case Z_DATA_ERROR:
 case Z_MEM_ERROR:
    (void)inflateEnd(&strm);
    return ret;
}
```

Now, after running the compression

```
$ ./zpipe < file.txt > file.gz
```

Then everything runs without errors

But when I try to decompress

```
$ ./zpipe -d < file.gz > file.dec.txt
```

Then I obtain an error related to `Z_DATA_ERROR`:

```
zpipe: invalid or incomplete deflate data
```

This error does not show up when implementing the deflateSetDictionary calls. I am aware that this error is related to deflateSetDictionary, and perhaps when implemented using buffers, since there is no error when running other examples with dictionaries (such as http://www.chuntey.com/Source/Zlib/example.c)

Comment: What does this mean: "For good measure, I added the deflateSetDictionary and every point before calling deflate()"?  `deflateSetDictionary` should only be called once, immediately following `deflateInit`.

Comment: instances of this line: 'int lenDict = (int) sizeof(dict);'  This will always return 32768, irregardless of the the contents of the dict[] array

Comment: @MarkAdler, that's what I thought at first, but then the manual says: "When using the zlib format, this function must be called immediately after deflateInit, deflateInit2 or deflateReset, and before any call of deflate.", where the wording of the last part I thought somewhat unclear. I had initially also tried with just one call, immediately following deflateInit... will try again, though.

Comment: @user3629249, the number of bytes of the dictionary is also 32768, but you're right that i need to modify to have strlen()

Comment: That means that you _cannot_ call `deflateSetDictionary()` _after_ any `deflate()` call.  Once you call `deflate()`, you cannot call `deflateSetDictionary()` on that stream unless you do a `deflateReset()` to start over.  Just call `deflateSetDictionary()` once immediately after `deflateInit()` or `inflateInit()`.

Comment: @MarkAdler, Sorry for the double post. I had only implemented this latter mistake after I had tried other things. But the error persists. Maybe the error is in the inf() part? 
I summarize the zlib calls made below, though the only diff. w.r.t. to zpipe.c is the {de,in}flateSetDictionary calls

 
In def():
 `deflateInit()`
 `deflateSetDictionary()`
 `do{ // compress until EOF`
  `do{ // until output buffer not full
      deflate()
  }
 }
 `deflateEnd()`

In inf():
  `inflateInit()`
  `do {`
   `ret = inflate()`
   `if ret==Z_NEED_DICT`
     `deflateInitDictionary()` 
   `}`
   `inflateEnd()`

Comment: After the `inflateSetDictionary()` you need to run `inflate()` again.  Otherwise you'll fall out of the inner loop and overwrite the input that was read.

Answer (score 1):

After the `inflateSetDictionary()` you need to run `inflate()` again. Otherwise you'll fall out of the inner loop and overwrite the input that was read. – Mark Adler